Unable to Connect Scylladb From Scala, Scylladb Nodes are Running in Kubernetes
I'm trying to run Scylladb Nodes in k8s and access them from Scala (Phantom Library).
Kubernetes
Firstly I've followed commands from official scylladb documentation to create scylladb cluster.
$ minikube start --cpus=6
$ eval $(minikube docker-env)
$ git clone https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-operator.git
$ cd scylla-operator
$ kubectl apply -f examples/common/cert-manager.yaml
$ kubectl wait --for condition=established crd/certificates.cert-manager.io crd/issuers.cert-manager.io
$ kubectl -n cert-manager rollout status deployment.apps/cert-manager-webhook
$ kubectl apply -f deploy/operator.yaml
$ kubectl wait --for condition=established crd/scyllaclusters.scylla.scylladb.com
$ kubectl -n scylla-operator rollout status deployment.apps/scylla-operator
$ kubectl create -f examples/generic/cluster.yaml

After all above commands scylladb cluster got ready, I've checked using some commands:
$ kubectl -n scylla get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
simple-cluster-us-east-1-us-east-1a-0   2/2     Running   0          90m
simple-cluster-us-east-1-us-east-1a-1   2/2     Running   0          80m
simple-cluster-us-east-1-us-east-1a-2   0/2     Pending   0          77m


$ kubectl -n scylla get svc
NAME                                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                                                          AGE
simple-cluster-client                   ClusterIP   10.98.139.252   <none>        7000/TCP,7001/TCP,9042/TCP,9142/TCP,19042/TCP,19142/TCP,7199/TCP,10001/TCP,9180/TCP,5090/TCP,9100/TCP,9160/TCP   90m
simple-cluster-us-east-1-us-east-1a-0   ClusterIP   10.98.37.120    <none>        7000/TCP,7001/TCP,9042/TCP,9142/TCP,19042/TCP,19142/TCP,7199/TCP,10001/TCP,9180/TCP,5090/TCP,9100/TCP,9160/TCP   90m
simple-cluster-us-east-1-us-east-1a-1   ClusterIP   10.105.171.34   <none>        7000/TCP,7001/TCP,9042/TCP,9142/TCP,19042/TCP,19142/TCP,7199/TCP,10001/TCP,9180/TCP,5090/TCP,9100/TCP,9160/TCP   90m
simple-cluster-us-east-1-us-east-1a-2   ClusterIP   10.110.32.166   <none>        7000/TCP,7001/TCP,9042/TCP,9142/TCP,19042/TCP,19142/TCP,7199/TCP,10001/TCP,9180/TCP,5090/TCP,9100/TCP,9160/TCP   90m


$ kubectl exec -n scylla -it simple-cluster-us-east-1-us-east-1a-0 -- nodetool status
Defaulted container "scylla" out of: scylla, scylla-manager-agent, sidecar-injection (init)
Datacenter: us-east-1
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.98.37.120   108.99 KB  256          ?       a1d76285-964f-48b1-b87d-2e2fafa96877  us-east-1a
UN  10.105.171.34  201.48 KB  256          ?       c2204fec-b713-4fd5-ba47-d8b72505ac12  us-east-1a

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless


After setting above scylladb cluster, now I need to access it via my scala code.
Scala
schema.scala:
abstract class MyDataSchema extends Table[MyDataSchema, MyData] {

  override def tableName: String = "mydata"

  object myColumn extends OptionalStringColumn with PartitionKey {
    override def name: String = "myColumn"
  }
}

connection.scala:
class ScyllaDBConnection extends ScyllaDBConnectionTrait {

  override def connectionProvider: CassandraConnection = {
    val applicationConf: Config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
    val keyspace: String = applicationConf.getString("keyspace.keyspaceName")
    val connection: CassandraConnection =
      ContactPoints(List("10.98.139.252")) //10.98.139.252 is IP of Service
        .keySpace(keyspace)
    connection
  }

}

database.scala:
class MyDB(override val connector: CassandraConnection)
  extends Database[MyDB](connector) {
  object MyData extends MyDataSchema with Connector
}

Now the problem is whenever I run this, it gives an error:
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /10.98.139.252 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/10.98.139.252] Cannot connect))

I've tried different things in:
connection.scala:
class ScyllaDBConnection extends ScyllaDBConnectionTrait {

  override def connectionProvider: CassandraConnection = {
    val applicationConf: Config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
    val keyspace: String = applicationConf.getString("keyspace.keyspaceName")
    val connection: CassandraConnection =
      ContactPoints(List("10.98.139.252")) //10.98.139.252 is IP of Service
        .keySpace(keyspace)
    connection
  }

}

I've tried to give pod IP, service IP, scylladb node IP and service name to connect ContactPoints but nothing worked for me.
Guide me how can I connect my above scala service with Scylladb Cluster which is running on Kubernetes.

Where is your Scala code running? Inside the Kubernetes cluster as well? Otherwise you won't be able to connect just like that. Also you should not use IPs directly but rather the service name.

@GaëlJ I've created image of my scala application and run inside Kubernetes Cluster, also I've given service name instead of IPs. It is not working as well.
Could this also be a firewall issue?
